# Risks of using performSelectorInBackground?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, ios

I have been doing some testing with [ObjectiveResource](http://iphoneonrails.com/) (iOS->Rails bridge). Things seem to work, but the library is synchronous (or maybe not, but [the mailing list that supports it is a mess](http://groups.google.com/group/objectiveresource/browse_thread/thread/6f05ed9f4df0c3ba/9fdd338d72ef9c33?lnk=gst&q=async#9fdd338d72ef9c33)).

**I'm wondering what the pitfalls are to just running all calls in a `performSelectorInBackground`**... in small tests it seems to work fine, but that's the case with many things that are wrong.

The only caveat I've noticed is that you have to create an Autorelease Pool in the method called by performSelectorInBackground (and then you should only call `drain` and not `release`?).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`performSelectorInBackground:` uses threads behind the scenes, and the big thing with threads is that any piece of code touched by more than one is a minefield for race conditions and other subtle bugs. This obviously means drawing to the screen is off-limits outside the main thread. But there are a lot of other libraries that are also not threadsafe, and any code using those is also tainted.

Basically, thread-safety is something you have to intentionally put in your code or it's probably not there. ObjectiveResource doesn't make any claims to it, so already I would be nervous. Glancing at the source, it looks like it mainly uses the Foundation URL loading machinery, which is threadsafe IIRC. But the ObjectiveResource code itself is not. Just at a glance, all of the class methods use static variables, which means they're all subject to race conditions if you `performSelectorInBackground:` more than once with code that uses them.

It looks like the 1.1 branch on their Github has explicit support for async through a ConnectionManager class. Probably better off using that (though this is essentially unmaintained code, so caveat emptor).

Comment: Thanks so much for that analysis, @Chuck. I think that once of the sources of the problem with ObjResource is that they do everything with categories instead of inheritance, which is nice (frees up your inheritance line) but REALLY limiting in Obj-C because you can't have variables in categories. Anyway, I think I might be making too much of this: for a "business" app, blocking, synchronous calls are probably just fine.

Comment: is it safe to make UIView pieces in the background thread, as long as I don't attach them to any visible view while there?

Answer (score 8):

So are you actually experiencing any issues? Or are you just anticipating them?

Running on a background thread shouldn't give you any issues, unless you try to update a UI element from that same background thread. Be sure to forward any UI-related activities to the main thread. For example (pseudo):

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(refreshTableView)];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)refreshTableView {
    // Where _listOfObjects is used to populate your UITableView
    @synchronized(self) {
        self._listOfObjects = [MyDataType findAllRemote];
    }
    [self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
}
```

**Note** also (as above) that if you are changing the value of any instance variables on the background thread, it's important that you synchronize on `self` to prevent any other threads (like the main thread) from accessing objects in the `_listOfObjects` array while it is being updated or set. (Or you may "get" an incomplete object.)

I'm not 100% positive (comments are welcome), but I believe that if you declare the `_listOfObjects` property as `atomic`, you won't need to worry about the synchronized block. **Though**, you would need the synchronized block regardless of the `@property` declaration if, instead of reassigning the value of the property, you were instead making changes to a single, persistent instance. (Eg. Adding/removing objects from a static NSMutableArray.)

Comment: I would say I'm anticipating issues. Right now if I bring down the Rails server, ObjectiveResource immediately returns with wrong answers (0 for record count instead of returning an error). I agree that unless you're adjusting the object itself, atomic should be sufficient. Oh, and you need a new autorelease pool for the background thread.

Comment: Good point - I forgot completely about the additional autorelease pool.

Comment: my comments on errors were wrong. It's got a mechanism to return errors.